# Exponentiate at different levels with tbl_regression in gtsummary

Tags: gtsummary

I would like to use tbl_regression in gtsummary to exponentiate for my ORs, but at different unit values. For example, I have a logistic regression model in which for some predictors I would like to express the OR per 5 or 10 unit increase (not just 1 unit increase). Is there anyway to do so?

Per my understanding of tbl_regression, I do not see a way to customize the exponentiate function.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible from within gtsummary, but it gets more complicated with exponentiation. I recommend just handling this before the model is passed to `tbl_regression()`. See example

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.7.0'

glm(response ~ identity(age/10) + grade, data = trial, family = binomial) |> 
  tbl_regression(
    exponentiate = TRUE,
    label = list("identity(age/10)" = "Age per 10yrs")
  ) |> 
  as_kable() # convert to kable to display on StackOverflow
```

| **Characteristic** | **OR** | **95% CI** | **p-value** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Age per 10yrs | 1.21 | 0.97, 1.52 | 0.10 |
| Grade |  |  |  |
| I | — | — |  |
| II | 0.85 | 0.39, 1.85 | 0.7 |
| III | 1.01 | 0.47, 2.16 | >0.9 |

<sup>Created on 2023-03-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>